# write an insert statement in shell and store it in a variable

Tags: shell, unix

I have to do this  an insert query into a variable and later use that variable but I am unable to do show because of the select *.

what I am doing is:-

```
a=today_39012123
b=`echo "insert into mytable select * from $a"`
echo $b
```

but on `echo $b` all aliases are showing.

I checked on terminal doing `echo *` prints the same thing as printed by * in $b.

how can I store that query in a varibale.

I also tried:-
b=`echo "insert into mytable select \* from $a"`
but I am getting output :- insert into mytable select * from today_39012123.
which is not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
a=today_39012123
set -o noglob 
b="insert into mytable select * from $a"
echo $b
set +o noglob
```

Comment: hmmmm its working..that means i have to execute that query with setting -o noglob..?